# how to create 100 jobs in jenkins at a time?

Tags: jenkins

**In one interviewer asked me how to create 100 jobs in jenkins at a time?**

**can you people clear my doubt?**

Comment: google search could be helpful.

Comment: they ask you these things because they assume you have experience in it? Are you lying on a resume??? ;D

Comment: No, but I didn't face this type of task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jenkins REST APIs. There is a help page at the bottom right of almost every Jenkins pages. It says

> To create a new job, post config.xml to [this URL](https://your-jenkins-server.com/jenkins/createItem) with query parameter name=JOBNAME. You need to send a Content-Type: application/xml header. You will get a 200 status code if the creation is successful, or 4xx/5xx code if it fails. config.xml is the format Jenkins uses to store the project in the file system, so you can see examples of them in the Jenkins home directory, or by retrieving the XML configuration of existing jobs from /job/JOBNAME/config.xml.

In short, send a POST to `your-jenkins-server.com/jenkins/createItem`. You may also need to send crumb as well.

So, the rest is up to you. Pick a language and maybe write a simple console program, or maybe, a simple website to send that HttpPost.